# Table with multiple rows and deletions

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html

Ok, so I have an input function that allows me to add items to a database, and displays this as a table. As part of the table, I am trying to add delete and edit buttons.

I am trying to figure out the best way to add delete and edit functionality. I'm thinking for editing, I will have to use Javascript. However, for deletions, I am not sure if I should use PHP, Javascript, or some combination therein.

So far, here's my code:

```
<html>
    <header><title>Generic Web App</title></header>
    <body>
        <form action="addculture.php" method="POST">
              <span><input type="text" size="3" name="id" />
              <input type="text" name="culture" />
            <input type="submit" value="add" /></span>
        </form>
<?php
/* VARIABLE NAMES
 *
 * $con = MySQL Connection 
 * $rescult = MySQL Culture Query
 * $cultrow = MySQL Culture Query Rows
 */
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("generic");
$rescult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM culture order by cult_id");
if (!$rescult) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql());
}
echo "<table><tbody><tr><th>ID</th><th>Culture Name</th>";
while ($cultrow = mysql_fetch_array($rescult)) {
    echo "<tr>" . "<td>" . $cultrow[0] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $cultrow[1] . "</td>" . '<td><button type="button">Del</button></td>' . '<td><button type="button">Edit</button></td>' . "</tr>";
}
echo "</tbody></table>";
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Currently I have del and edit set as buttons, just for visible reference. What's the best way to deal with a situation where you have multiple buttons like this?

Comment: do you want ajax edit & delete or just php in new pages ?

Comment: Just php, while I know some basic AJAX, it's still too complex for me at this point for the most part.

Comment: Currently I am just phping new pages, and then using Javascript to immediately redirect back to the main page. Perhaps not the most efficient way, but easy.

Answer (score 1):

I apologize if my answer is too broad but so is your question.

Both, Editing and Deleting should use a combination of JavaScript and PHP code; for example when the user clicks on the delete button you can send an Ajax request to the server, have the record deleted from the DB and upon successful return from the server-side call, use JavaScript to visually delete the record from the markup. The same would apply to the Edit functionality.

Here's a nice intro on how to perform ajax requests using JQuery:

http://www.devirtuoso.com/2009/07/beginners-guide-to-using-ajax-with-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

The first think I would do is add a value and name to the buttons:

```
<button type="button" value="$cultrow[0]" name="Delete">Delete</button>
<button type="button" value="$cultrow[0]" name="Edit">Edit</button>
```

The value of the button is going to be the id of the row, and the name is going to be the action that button will do. The next thing I would do is bind those buttons to actions with jquery.

```
$('button').click(function(){
 //determine whether is delete or edit
 //Once you determine what action use the id to make the request
 //if delete prompt to verify if yes, ajax the server with a delete request
 //if edit redirect user to a page that will handle editing of the row edit.php?id=5
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For deleting row

1 - Make new page name it del_culture.php

```
session_start(); 
$id = base64_decode($_GET['id']); 
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$q = mysql_query("DELETE FROM culture WHERE cult_id = '".$id."' ");
if($q):
   echo "Done"; 
else:
   echo "ERROR";
endif;
```

2 - in your page add the following code

```
 while ($cultrow = mysql_fetch_array($rescult)) 
{

echo "<tr>" . "<td>" . $cultrow[0] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $cultrow[1] . "</td>" . '    
<td><a href="del_culture.php?id='.base64_encode($cultrow['cult_id']).'">Delete</a>' . '<td><button type="button">Edit</button></td>' . "</tr>";
}
```

For Editing a row add link for edit like i did to page name it edit_cult.php
and do the same as you input put the values from database and then update it

Answer (score 0):

This is your javascript

```
function performAction(action) {
// ASSIGN THE ACTION
var action = action;

// UPDATE THE HIDDEN FIELD
document.getElementById("action").value = action;

switch(action) {

    case "delete":
        //we get an array with every input contained into the form, and the form have an id
        var aryCheck=document.getElementById('adminform').getElementsByTagName('input');

        //now we parse them
        var elm=null;
        var total=0;

        for(cptCnt=0;cptCnt<aryCheck.length;cptCnt++) {
            elm=aryCheck[cptCnt];
            if(elm.type=='checkbox') {
                //we have a checkbox here
                if(elm.checked==true){
                    total++;
                }
            }
        }
        if(total > 0) {
            if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete the selected records?")) {
                // SUBMIT THE FORM
                document.adminform.submit();
            }
        }
        else {
            alert("You didn't select any records");
        }
        break;




    case "edit":
        //we get an array with every input contained into the form, and the form have an id
        var aryCheck=document.getElementById('adminform').getElementsByTagName('input');

        //now we parse them
        var elm=null;
        var total=0;

        for(cptCnt=0;cptCnt<aryCheck.length;cptCnt++) {
            elm=aryCheck[cptCnt];
            if(elm.type=='checkbox') {
                //we have a checkbox here
                if(elm.checked==true){
                    total++;
                }
            }
        }
        if(total > 1) {
            alert("You can only edit one record at a time");
        }
        else if(total == 0) {
            alert("You didn't select a record");
        }
        else {
            document.adminform.submit();
        }
        break;


    default:
}
```

}

and in your form you need something like this

```
<form id="adminform" name="adminform" action="<?php $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>" method="post">
<img src="/admin/images/news.png" alt="news" title="news" />
<input type="button" class="back" id="backbutton" title="go back" onclick="performAction('back');" />
<input type="button" class="delete" id="deletebutton" title="delete" onclick="performAction('delete');" />
<input type="button" class="archive" id="archivebutton" title="archive" onclick="performAction('archive');" />
<input type="button" class="edit" id="editbutton" title="edit" onclick="performAction('edit');" />
<input type="button" class="add" id="addbutton" title="add" onclick="performAction('add');" />

<table id="admintable"> 
    <tr><th class='tdleft'>
        <?php
        if($err !=0) {
            echo"<input type='checkbox' name='all' onclick='checkAll(adminform);' />";
        }   
        echo "</th><th class='tdright'>Title</th></tr>";
        $z = 0;
        // Iterate through the results
        while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
            if($z % 2==0) { 
                //this means if there is a remainder
                echo "<tr class='yellow'>\n";
                $z++;
            } else { 
                //if there isn't a remainder we will do the else
                echo "<tr class='white'>\n";
                $z++;
            }
            echo "<td class='tdleft'><input type='checkbox' name='id[]' value='{$row['id']}' /></td><td class='tdright'><a href='/admin/news/edit-news-".$row['id']."'>{$row['title']}</a></td></tr>";  
        }
    ?>  
</table>
<input type="hidden" id="action" name="action"  value="" />
```

and at the top of your page before the html put
   if($_POST && array_key_exists("action", $_POST)){

```
        // CARRY OUT RELAVANT ACTION
        switch($_POST['action']) {
            case "edit":

                foreach($_POST['id'] as $value) {
                    $id = $value;
                }   
                header('Location: /admin/blogs/edit-blog-'.$id);
                break;
            case "delete":
                if(!empty($_POST['id'])) {
                    //do your delete here
                }
                break;

            }
        }
            }
```